# Postback and Return URL in Opencart

Tags: php, api, opencart, payment-gateway

I need help on finding/configuring the post-back and return URL on Opencart. I have successfully integrated the Dragonpay **[Payment Gateway API](http://www.dragonpay.ph/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Dragonpay-PS-API.pdf)**.

However, I need to know the Postback and return URL's so they can configure it on their system. How do I know the postback & return URL?

```
    public function callback() {
    if (isset($this->request->get['txnid'])) {
        $order_id = $this->request->get['txnid'];
    } else {
        $order_id = 0;
    }
    $this->load->model('checkout/order');
    $merchantid = $this->config->get('dragonpay_email');
    $ref_no = (isset($this->request->get['refno']))?$this->request->get['refno']:'';
    $status = (isset($this->request->get['status']))?$this->request->get['status']:'';
    $result = (isset($this->request->get['message']))?$this->request->get['message']:'';
    $passwd = $this->config->get('dragonpay_pwd');
    $rdigest_str = "$order_id:$ref_no:$status:$result:$passwd";
    $chk_rdigest = sha1($rdigest_str);      
    $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

    if ($order_info && isset($this->request->get['digest']) && $chk_rdigest==$this->request->get['digest']) {

        if (isset($this->request->get['status'])&&strtoupper($this->request->get['status'])=="S") {
            $order_status_id = $this->config->get('config_order_status_id');
            switch(strtoupper($result)) {
                case 'SUCESS':
                    $order_status_id = $this->config->get('dragonpay_completed_status_id');
                    break;
                case 'FAILURE':
                    $order_status_id = $this->config->get('dragonpay_failed_status_id');
                    break;
                case 'PENDING':
                    $order_status_id = $this->config->get('dragonpay_pending_status_id');
                    break;

            }
            if (!$order_info['order_status_id']) {
                $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order_id, $order_status_id);
            } else {
                $this->model_checkout_order->update($order_id, $order_status_id);
            }
        } else {
            $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order_id, $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'));
        }
    }
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/success', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post back and return URLs are those where You have your controller and actions waiting to be accessed and to do something with the data that is POSTed or queried there. Usually it goes like this:

1. you start a payment transaction which means you prepare the data to be sent, crypt them and post/query them to the payment gateway URL
2. after user finishes the payment (or even cancels it or there is another error) the payment gateway redirects the user back to a specific URL

   - usually those are *success URL* and *error URL*
3. In the case of success the URL might be `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?route=payment/yourpaygate/success` - here the payment gate sends the data so that in your store you can set the order as paid
4. In the case of error the URL might be `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?route=payment/yourpaygate/fail` - here you know that the payment was not finished and can set the order as pending, cancelled, whatever.

So you create/define those URLs and then give them to the payment gateway provider.

Comment: Hi shadyyx, thanks for your reply. I actually figured it out, i just realized they needed to set the postback url, on the payment gateway provider's backend side for the postback/returl url to work. Thanks for the reply! I appreciate it so much.